# tkinter button grid recognising specific buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a program where you toggle a button and the button changes colour when toggled 
this is what i have so far, 
sorry i've just started dabbling in tkinter and i'm still getting my head round it
and thanks in advance
:

```
from tkinter import *

xbuttons = 8
ybuttons = 5
scale = 100

root = Tk(className='tk')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
winsizex = xbuttons*scale
winsizey = ybuttons*scale
geometry = str(winsizey)+'x'+str(winsizex)
root.geometry(geometry)

frame=Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

def toggle():
    '''
    use
    t_btn.config('text')[-1]
    to get the present state of the toggle button
    '''
    if btn.config('bg')[-1] == 'white':
        btn.config(bg='black')
    else:
        btn.config(bg='white')


for row_index in range(xbuttons):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=1)
    for col_index in range(ybuttons):
        Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=1)
        btn = Button(frame, command = toggle, bg = "white")
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)  

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to change the color of the button you pressed?

Comment: Yes, after one of the buttons is pressed i want that button to toggle black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass an argument to your function,try:

```
def toggle(widget):
    '''
    use
    t_btn.config('text')[-1]
    to get the present state of the toggle button
    '''
    if widget.config('bg')[-1] == 'white':
        widget.config(bg='black')
    else:
        widget.config(bg='white')

for row_index in range(xbuttons):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=1)
    for col_index in range(ybuttons):
        Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=1)
        btn = Button(frame, bg = "white")
        btn["command"] = lambda widget = btn:toggle(widget)
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)

root.mainloop()
```

Also,there is easier way is to bind an event `<Button-1>`.